# Pulumi GitHub Action pulumi/actions@v2: error: It looks like the Pulumi SDK has not been installed. Have you run npm install or yarn install?

Tags: azure, npm, github-actions, pulumi, infrastructure-as-code

I'm working [on a project that uses Pulumi to provision some infrastructure pieces on Azure](https://github.com/jonashackt/azure-training-pulumi). I switched to the new [pulumi/actions@v2](https://github.com/pulumi/actions) Action [which was released recently](https://github.com/pulumi/actions/issues/73).

My GitHub Actions workflow looks like this:

```
name: pulumi-preview-up

on: [push]

env:
  ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID: ${{ secrets.ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID }}
  ARM_CLIENT_ID: ${{ secrets.ARM_CLIENT_ID }}
  ARM_CLIENT_SECRET: ${{ secrets.ARM_CLIENT_SECRET }}
  ARM_TENANT_ID: ${{ secrets.ARM_TENANT_ID }}
  PULUMI_ACCESS_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.PULUMI_ACCESS_TOKEN }}

jobs:
  preview-up-destroy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Install Pulumi CLI
        uses: pulumi/action-install-pulumi-cli@v1.0.1

      - uses: pulumi/actions@v2
        with:
          command: preview
          stack-name: dev
```

Now I bumped into the following error (see [the full GHA logs here](https://github.com/jonashackt/azure-training-pulumi/runs/2075614963?check_suite_focus=true)):

```
  Error: code: 255
   stdout: Previewing update (github-638882160)
  
  View Live: https://app.pulumi.com/jonashackt/scmbreakoutpulumi/github-638882160/previews/450a1f61-549d-4669-a7de-d8da8fc622f7
  
      pulumi:pulumi:Stack scmbreakoutpulumi-github-638882160  error: It looks like the Pulumi SDK has not been installed. Have you run npm install or yarn install?
      pulumi:pulumi:Stack scmbreakoutpulumi-github-638882160  1 message
   
  Diagnostics:
    pulumi:pulumi:Stack (scmbreakoutpulumi-github-638882160):
      error: It looks like the Pulumi SDK has not been installed. Have you run npm install or yarn install?
   
  
   stderr: error: failed to load language plugin nodejs: could not read plugin [/home/runner/.pulumi/bin/pulumi-language-nodejs] stdout: EOF
  
   err?:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new Pulumi v2 GitHub Action uses the [new Pulumi Automation API](https://www.pulumi.com/blog/automation-api/). As [the docs state](https://github.com/pulumi/actions#example-workflows):

> This means that there is no supporting functionality for npm or pip
> installs. This functionality should be deferred to the correct GitHub
> Marketplace actions that support it.

This means it's not sufficient anymore (as we were used to with Pulumi v1 Action) to configure the `pulumi/actions` and `pulumi/action-install-pulumi-cli` Actions. We **additionally need to set up the language specific GitHub Action environments ourselves** - AND need to **install the respective dependencies also ourselves** - *BEFORE* using the `pulumi/actions`!

Assuming to use Pulumi with JavaScript/Typscript style, we need to add the [actions/setup-node](https://github.com/actions/setup-node) Action and also run a `npm install` afterwards. In our `workflow.yml` it looks like this:

```
name: pulumi-preview-up

on: [push]

env:
  ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID: ${{ secrets.ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID }}
  ARM_CLIENT_ID: ${{ secrets.ARM_CLIENT_ID }}
  ARM_CLIENT_SECRET: ${{ secrets.ARM_CLIENT_SECRET }}
  ARM_TENANT_ID: ${{ secrets.ARM_TENANT_ID }}
  PULUMI_ACCESS_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.PULUMI_ACCESS_TOKEN }}

jobs:
  preview-up-destroy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: In order to use the Pulumi v2 action, we need to setup the Pulumi project specific language environment
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: '14'

      - name: After setting up the Pulumi project specific language environment, we need to install the dependencies also
        run: npm install

      - name: Install Pulumi CLI
        uses: pulumi/action-install-pulumi-cli@v1.0.1

      - uses: pulumi/actions@v2
        with:
          command: preview
          stack-name: dev
```

If you choose another language then JavaScript/TypeScript, you need to also setup the matching environment. The docs show [examples for Python, Go and .Net also](https://github.com/pulumi/actions#example-workflows).